# Accessing Subclassed Django Models through Tastypie's ToManyField

Tags: django, django-models, tastypie

I've got a setup containing a model which has a set of foreign-keyed objects which all inherit from a parent class. All the code surrounding this design is working well, but I'm currently in the process of integrating tastypie for API access.

I can't seem to get the tastypie to play well with one of the models in question. I've managed to get GET to work, but all attempts at making POST for creation or editing work either results in GET breaking, or nothing working at all. I've laid out example code and current attempts at fixing below.

Simplified Models:

```
class Container(models.Model):
    variable = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class ParentClass(models.Model):
    container = models.ForeignKey(Container)
    order = models.IntegerField()


class FirstInheritor(ParentClass):
    important_data = models.IntegerField(default=0)


class SecondInheritor(ParentClass):
    other_data = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

There's quite a bit more the the actual inheritor models in the full code, but the example has the same concept: multiple inheritors from a parent model which has a foreign-key to the model in question which I'm trying to enable api-usability for (Container).

Currently, I've got the tastypie resources looking something like this:

```
class FirstInheritorResource(resources.ModelResource):
    container = fields.ForeignKey('api.ContainerResource', 'container')

    class Meta:
        queryset = FirstInheritor.objects.all()
        authorization = Authorization()
        allowed_methods = ['get', 'post']


class SecondInheritorResource(resources.ModelResource):
    container = fields.ForeignKey('api.ContainerResource', 'container')

    class Meta:
        queryset = SecondInheritor.objects.all()
        authorization = Authorization()
        allowed_methods = ['get', 'post']


class ContainerResource(resources.ModelResource):
    firsts = fields.ToManyField(FirstInheritorResource, attribute=lambda bundle: FirstInheritor.objects.filter(container=bundle.obj), related_name="parentclass", full=True, null=True)
    seconds = fields.ToManyField(SecondInheritorResource, attribute=lambda bundle: SecondInheritor.objects.filter(container=bundle.obj), related_name="parentclass", full=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        queryset = Container.objects.all()
        authorization = Authorization()
        allowed_methods = ['get', 'post']
```

With this code the GET request obviously works. I've tried tweaking the related_name of "firsts" and "seconds" to just about every possible thing (parentclass, container, firstinheritor), and have tried to fiddle with the attribute of these two ToManyFields, but since there is no -direct- connection between Container and the two Inheritor models, they can't find one another.

I've tried subclassing the toManyField and rewriting many of it's functions to see the effect of changing things, or forcing certain variables, but I've had no luck.

As it is currently configured, attempting to post data with firsts or seconds results in

```
{"error": "The 'container' field has no data and doesn't allow a default or null value."}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I think I've solved the issue here.

Firstly, I subclassed the parent model to a model to the follwing:

```
class InheritableOrderedModel(models.Model):
real_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, editable=False,)

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.id:
        self.real_type = self._get_real_type()
    super(InheritableOrderedModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

def _get_real_type(self):
    return ContentType.objects.get_for_model(type(self))

def cast(self):
    return self.real_type.get_object_for_this_type(pk=self.pk)

class Meta:
    abstract = True
```

I'm not sure how efficient this is, but it's currently working to allow me to get the real class of the various children.

Then I created a new field type. I altered the get_related_resources and build_related resources specifically for the children I have, so this isn't a perfectly scalable solution currently:

```
class PolymorphicRelatedField(fields.ToManyField):
def get_related_resource(self, related_instance):
    """
    Instaniates the related resource.
    """
    to = {
        FirstInheritor: FirstInheritorResource,
        SecondInheritor: SecondInheritorResource,

    }

    # Try to cast this item to it's real component
    try:
        related_model = related_instance.cast().__class__
        related_instance = related_instance.cast()
        related_resource = to[related_model]()
        print(related_model)
    except:
        related_resource = self.to_class()

    print "RELATED INSTANCE POSTFIX", related_instance
    # Fix the ``api_name`` if it's not present.
    if related_resource._meta.api_name is None:
        if self._resource and not self._resource._meta.api_name is None:
            related_resource._meta.api_name = self._resource._meta.api_name

    # Try to be efficient about DB queries.
    related_resource.instance = related_instance
    return related_resource

def build_related_resource(self, value, request=None, related_obj=None, related_name=None):
        """
        Returns a bundle of data built by the related resource, usually via
        ``hydrate`` with the data provided.
        Accepts either a URI, a data dictionary (or dictionary-like structure)
        or an object with a ``pk``.
        """
        # Override the resource type based on the "type"
        if 'type' in value:
            thistype = value.pop('type')
            if thistype == "FirstInheritor":
                self.fk_resource = FirstInheritorResource()
            elif thistype == "SecondInheritor":
                self.fk_resource = SecondInheritorResource()
        else:
            self.fk_resource = self.to_class()

        kwargs = {
            'request': request,
            'related_obj': related_obj,
            'related_name': related_name,
        }

        if isinstance(value, Bundle):
            # Already hydrated, probably nested bundles. Just return.
            return value
        elif isinstance(value, six.string_types):
            # We got a URI. Load the object and assign it.
            return self.resource_from_uri(self.fk_resource, value, **kwargs)
        elif hasattr(value, 'items'):
            # We've got a data dictionary.
            # Since this leads to creation, this is the only one of these
            # methods that might care about "parent" data.
            return self.resource_from_data(self.fk_resource, value, **kwargs)
        elif hasattr(value, 'pk'):
            # We've got an object with a primary key.
            return self.resource_from_pk(self.fk_resource, value, **kwargs)
        else:
            raise ApiFieldError("The '%s' field was given data that was not a URI, not a dictionary-alike and does not have a 'pk' attribute: %s." % (self.instance_name, value))
```

I also made the dehydrate function the children resources return a "type" field. The POST mirrors this, and expects a "type" field for each of the children objects. The build_related_resources looks for this field and casts the objects to their expected classes.

Then I needed to add another resource for the parent object

```
class ParentResource(resources.ModelResource):
container = fields.ForeignKey('api.ContainerResource', 'container')

class Meta:
    queryset = ParentClass.objects.all()
    authorization = Authorization()
    allowed_methods = ['get', 'post']
```

And change the container resource to be:

```
class ContainerResource(resources.ModelResource):
    children = PolymorphicRelatedField(ParentResource, attribute=parentclass_set, related_name='container', null=True, full=True)

class Meta:
    queryset = Container.objects.all()
    authorization = Authorization()
    allowed_methods = ['get', 'post']
```

The result is the api allowing for the creation of related children fields, as well as displaying the related fields properly in a GET request.

I have yet to test this with editing of fields, and probably need to iron out some bugs I haven't found yet.

I should note that during the process of solving this issue, I discovered Django-Polymorphic. This solution would also work easily with django-polymorphic instead of the "IngeritableOrderedModel" class and using a different method of casting in the get_related_fields method.